# Stuck on trying to Create an upload keystore

Tags: flutter, keystore, android-keystore

I am currently tring to create an upload keystore, but I am stuck with the problem:

`The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.`

I ran flutter doctor -v, located the java folder, but still wasn't able to sucessfully create it.

I tried this:

`lucasmatias@Lucass-Mac-mini cspro % Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA \ -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it from Java... basically, do something like this before generating:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin
```

(the equivalent for MAC)

then your command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA \ -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```